# Increasing Functions in Non-deterministic Time Hierarchy Theorems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, hierarchy-theorems, time-hierarchy

I was going over the proofs of the non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem (the one in Arora-Barak and the one by Fortnow and Santhanam). They are available here:

1. http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf : page 67
2. https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2011/04/new-proof-of-nondeterministic-time.html

It seems to me that we need $f$ and $g$ to be *increasing functions*, in addition to the usual assumptions that $f(n+1)=o(g(n))$ and time-constructibility.

1. In the Arora-Barak proof, we divide the natural numbers into disjoint intervals. I'm not sure how one can find, given a number $n$, which interval it lies in, without assuming that functions are increasing.
2. In the Fortnow-Santhanam proof, this is needed to ensure that $t_1(i+m+2)$ (which I believe may be a typo and should be in terms of $t_2$) can be computed in time $O(t_2(n))$.